# Get multiple column values from joined table in a comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 3 tables which contains rows like below:

**RESEARCH_REPORTS** table:

```
REPORT_ID   TOPIC
141         My Report Topic Title
142         Another Report Topic Title
143         Yet Another Report Topic Title
...
```

**PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL** table:

```
REPORT_ID    PROGRAM_AREA_ID
141          6
141          11
141          12
...
```

**PROGRAM_AREAS** table:

```
PROGRAM_AREA_ID    TITLE
6                  Program Area One
11                 Program Area Two
12                 Program Area Three
...
```

This query is currently returning me the results from down below:

```sql
SELECT rr.report_id, rr.topic, pa.title as program_areas 
FROM RESEARCH_REPORTS rr 
INNER JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL parr ON rr.report_id = parr.report_id 
INNER JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS pa ON parr.program_area_id = pa.program_area_id 
WHERE rr.report_id = 141
```

**Query Results**:

```
report_id    topic                    program_areas
141          My Report Topic Title    Program Area One
141          My Report Topic Title    Program Area Two
141          My Report Topic Title    Program Area Three
```

I need a select query which results in the following format:

**Preferred Query Results**:

```
report_id    topic                    program_areas
141          My Report Topic Title    Program Area One, Program Area Two, Program Area Three
```

How can I accomplish this on my current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string_agg()` function:-

```
SELECT rr.report_id, rr.topic, string_agg(pa.title,',') as program_areas 
FROM RESEARCH_REPORTS rr 
INNER JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS_REPORTS_REL parr ON rr.report_id = parr.report_id 
INNER JOIN PROGRAM_AREAS pa ON parr.program_area_id = pa.program_area_id 
WHERE rr.report_id = 141
group by rr.report_id, rr.topic
```